# Can I make the Android Studio Layout Resource File for SMALL XML include Nexus ONE and Nexus S phones?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-screen-support, android-layout

Currently, in Android Studio when I create a Layout Resource File and pick the size SMALL, the small sizes are referred to as only the Android Wear (Watch) sizes.

However, instead of the Android Wear to be considered "Small" xml file, I'd like to make it that only Nexus S and Nexus ONE phone sizes are in the "small" xml. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus One's screen is 480x800 pixels, at 252 pixels per inch. This places it in the `hdpi` category, which means that it has approximately a 320x533 dp screen.

Here is the definition of a `normal` screen:

> `normal`: Screens that are of similar size to a medium-density HVGA screen. The minimum layout size for a normal screen is approximately 320x470 dp units. Examples of such screens a WQVGA low-density, HVGA medium-density, WVGA high-density.

Therefore, the Nexus One is a `normal` screen size, and there's nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: I added the <support_screens/> code and it didn't change anything. So if my sign up button = 259dp layout_width and 79dp layout_height on the Nexus 6 devices, why doesn't the system take care of it for Nexus ONE and Nexus S phones? Instead on those phones it's exactly the same size which makes the imageButton look HUGE compared to the screen size. How would I make that imageButton a different size for Nexus ONE and Nexus S while leaving the 259dp and 79dp for Nexus 6?

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about the purpose of the dp unit (which is to make views with dp sizes the same _phsyical_ size on any device). So it makes perfect sense that something that is 259x79dp would appear to be the same size, regardless of device screen size/density.

Comment: So this same button on 2 different screen sizes appears too big on Nexus ONE and fine on Nexus 6.  So what do I do to make that button look smaller for the small screens?

Comment: I could say "declare a dimension resource with different values in different smallest-width directories", but I imagine that wouldn't be very helpful. I recommend reading https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html